# How to Get data from controller into service and then return by service into controller to use in html view

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

How to Get data from controller into service and then return by service into controller to use in html view
This is my service file

```
mymodule.service("rest",function(Restangular){
return  {
        save:  function(tablename,data){
            Restangular.all(tablename).post(data).then(function(resp){

            })
        }
      }})
```

And this is in my controller file

```
rest.save('custom_work',$scope.newtype)
                    toastrservice.success("New Type Added SuccessFully")
                    $scope.newtype =""
```

I just want to get the saved data from resp service to controller and want to display in HTML page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close with the code you have, you just have to return the function inside your service and do the .then inside of your controller. This should work in your case assuming the other code is correct:-

```
mymodule.service("rest",function(Restangular){
return  {
    save:  function(tablename,data){
        return Restangular.all(tablename).post(data);
    }
}})

rest.save('custom_work',$scope.newtype).then(function(response){
    // Use response variable for the response from service.
    toastrservice.success("New Type Added SuccessFully")
    $scope.newtype =""
})
```